# PHP form editor?

Tags: php, html, forms, content-management-system

I was told by my boss to make some plguin for the site, where people can define their own forms. And he was like

> There are some free ones, just find one suitible and rework it for the site.

So yeah, ain't found what I was looking for. Are there any? I'd need an open form editor in PHP which allows me to make some changes anywhere. Hope you can help me.

Comment: This wold be interesting.. I also need a similar thing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author [here](http://mount-kinabalu-borneo.com/blog/php-form-generator-for-webmaster-which-one-is-the-best.html) discusses about three open source form generators, may be this could be a starting lead for you:

- [PHP Form Generator for webmasters – which one is the best? (by Drizad; 8 Mar 2007)](http://mount-kinabalu-borneo.com/blog/php-form-generator-for-webmaster-which-one-is-the-best.html)

Comment: @LambdaDusk: Why do you then accept the answer? I mean look at the date. The answer was given in 2011, the blog post is four years earlier in 2007.

Answer (score 1):

If you know PHP, you might consider the form library [Zebra_Form](http://stefangabos.ro/php-libraries/zebra-form/) It seems to be one of the leanest, straight forward form frameworks out there. Requirements are basically just PHP & MySQL. There are frameworks like Symfony and Zend that have form libraries, but they are a lot more complicated.